# Dataframe with Path column - creating new columns

Tags: python, pandas, path

I have the following dataframe. I want to create new columns based on the FilePath column.

```
FilePath
S:\\colab\a.csv
S:\\colab\b.csv
S:\\colab\c.csv
S:\\colab\apple\dog.txt
S:\\colab\apple\cat.pdf
```

Below is the expected output. I want to get the hierarchy of the files in a string and convert "" to ">" and remove "S:\" in the file path. I also want to get counts for the amount of files and directories based on the file path. For example the first instance has a filecnt of 3 because they're 3 files in the directory colab (a.csv, b.csv, c.csv) and one directory (apple).

How can I do this in python?

Expected Output:

```
FilePath                   Hierarchy         FileCnt   DirCnt
S:\\colab\a.csv            colab             3         1
S:\\colab\b.csv            colab             3         1
S:\\colab\c.csv            colab             3         1
S:\\colab\apple\dog.txt    colab > apple     2         0
S:\\colab\apple\cat.pdf    colab > apple     2         0
```

So far I have

```
df['Hierarchy'] = df['FilePath'].str[4:].str.replace('\', ' > ')
```

Comment: how do you compute `DirCnt`?

Comment: Directory count is the number of directories inside the last outer directory. For example record 1 has a directory count of 1 because colab only has one directory inside it (apple). Additionally record 3 has a directory count of 0 because the directory apple has no directories inside. So basically the count of directories in the last directory in the hierarchy column (if theres no file extension)

Comment: @Eisen, in record 1, there is no apple directory.

Comment: Yes but apple exists in the colab directory as you can see in line 4

Comment: I think it would require getting everything after the last directory and grouping to get counts of the files (anything with an extension)?

Comment: i able to solve Hierarchy, Filecnt...Dont understand how dircnt works

Answer (score 0):

Making helper columns helps you get the counts of files and directories

```py
import pandas as pd

splits = df['FilePath'].str.split('\\')
df['Hierarchy'] = splits.str[1:-1].str.join(' > ')

# Before/Final is before the last directory
df['Before/Final'] = splits.str[-3]

# Final/Dir is the last directory
df['Final/Dir'] = splits.str[-2]

# FileCnt is the number of files in the last directory (number of times it's Final/Dir appears in the column)
df['FileCnt'] = df.groupby('Final/Dir')['Final/Dir'].transform('count')

# Create a dictionary of the number of directories in the last directory {Final/Dir: DirCnt}
dir_cnt = df.groupby('Before/Final')['Final/Dir'].nunique().to_dict()

# DirCnt is the number of directories in the last directory, if it's not in the dictionary then it's 0
df['DirCnt'] = df['Final/Dir'].map(dir_cnt).fillna(0).astype(int)

# you can delete the columns you don't need
df.drop(['Before/Final', 'Final/Dir'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

The extra columns:

| FilePath | Hierarchy | Before/Final | Final/Dir | FileCnt | DirCnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S:\colab\a.csv | colab | S: | colab | 3 | 1 |
| S:\colab\b.csv | colab | S: | colab | 3 | 1 |
| S:\colab\c.csv | colab | S: | colab | 3 | 1 |
| S:\colab\apple\dog.txt | colab > apple | colab | apple | 2 | 0 |
| S:\colab\apple\cat.pdf | colab > apple | colab | apple | 2 | 0 |

The dir_cnt dictionary:

| Final/Dir | DirCnt |
| --- | --- |
| S: | 1 |
| colab | 1 |